# Highlighting submenu without highlighting main menu

Tags: html, asp.net, menu

I have a menu which is displayed with submenus adjacent to it.

```
            foreach (Category menuItem in lstMenu)
        {
            if (menuItem.ParentID == 0) //if its a main menu element
            {
                if (menuItem.CategoryID == requestedid)//if its the requested menu, highlight it
                {
                    objStringBuilder.Append("<li class='active'><a href='Listing?id=" + menuItem.CategoryID + "&name=" + menuItem.CategoryDescription + "'>" + menuItem.CategoryDescription + "</a></li>");
                }
                else// if not, then dont
                {
                    objStringBuilder.Append("<li><a href='Listing?id=" + menuItem.CategoryID + "&name=" + menuItem.CategoryDescription + "'>" + menuItem.CategoryDescription + "</a></li>");
                }
            }
            else //if its a submenu element
            {
                if (menuItem.CategoryID == requestedid)//if its the requested submenu, highlight it
                {
                    objStringBuilder.Append("<ul class='nav navbar-nav2'><li class='active'><a href='Listing?id=" + menuItem.CategoryID + "&name=" + menuItem.CategoryDescription + "'>" + menuItem.CategoryDescription + "</a></li></ul>");
                }
                else// if not, then dont
                {
                    objStringBuilder.Append("<ul class='nav navbar-nav2'><li><a href='Listing?id=" + menuItem.CategoryID + "&name=" + menuItem.CategoryDescription + "'>" + menuItem.CategoryDescription + "</a></li></ul>");
                }
            }
        }
```

What I need is, when the submenu is highlighted, the main menu element shouldn't be. Curently it highlights the submenu (when submenu is requested) alongwith the main menu element (the submenu's parent). What can I do?

Comment: Try giving your main menu element a different class so that you can define different style. Put your code on jsfiddle so people can better help you

Comment: sorry I am not allowed to make changes to the css.

Comment: The element is highlighted because it is given the class of active. If you cannot change the css you can modify above js to remove the first  class='active' from your code and all your main menu will never be highlighted.

Comment: 1.Its not js, its C#
2.I know why the menu is highlighted. Probably you dint understand the issue. I want the menu to be highlighted when the menu is requested. But when the SubMenu is requested, I want the menu to be normal.

Comment: okay mate, I don't know c# but I figure scripts are not much different. I would say you can rearrange your if statement to do the following, if any of the submenu is selected, mark all main menu as not selected, would that makes sense to you? good luck.

Comment: aye aye captain........